# Running a .java file from a seperate.java mac

Tags: java, macos, desktop

Im having trouble with using Desktop.getDesktop().open(). Im trying to run one java file from another one, using this code:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class OpenFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String program = "HelloWorld.java";

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(program));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(program + " if not on the desktop");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a file called HelloWorld.java sitting on my desktop, but I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: HelloWorld.java doesn't exist.
    at java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:210)
    at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:270)
    at OpenFile.main(OpenFile.java:10)
```

I'm on a Mac, so that may be the problem but I'm not sure. I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: Java files don't "run" on their own.  First they need to be compiled.  You're not going to be able to run HelloWorld.java.  You might be able to, for example, run "java -cp . HelloWorld" in the directory that the **compiled** .class file lives.

Comment: Adding the entire path of the file worked, but Ill also try "java -cp . HelloWorld". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues that I see here.

1. You want to "run" a Java program, which is not the same as "opening" a Java file.
2. Even if you are trying to "open" a Java file using `Desktop.getDesktop().open`, this does not mean that `getDesktop().open` points to your "Desktop" folder from where you can open a file on your Mac's Desktop.

> 1. To execute your Java program, you need to first compile the Java program using the Java compiler. Then you would be able to "run" your program.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac /Users/username/Desktop/HelloWorld.java");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -classpath /Users/username/Desktop HelloWorld");
```

> 2. The `Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file)` method simply opens the selected file in the default application for that file type. For example, on a Mac, a text file would be opened by `TextEdit.app`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This has been very helpful